# how can I create a table 'post' where author can be of various types

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.. lets say 'staff' and 'customer'. Now anyone who can post on the social networking site has to be either staff or a customer..

I have created another table by the name 'post' but how can I keep track of the author using foreign key constraint if author can be of any two types and they are also stored in two different tables. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may try the db stackexchange for questions like this, instead: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: after a little research i wanted to know about database inheritance..

Answer (score 1):

You are asking more about normalization practices rather than a true/false type question.

It is difficult to imagine what you're attempting without a schema, but it is likely better that you use a single table for users (staff and customer) and have a column that foreign-keys over to a user-type table.  Then you only have a single user_id PK to use as your FK in your posts table.

Comment: thanks.. but one more question.. lets say i have three columns(say id-PK, staff_id and customer_id) later two nullable, then how do i keep a check using schema that both staff_id and customer_id are not NULL together at once.. is it even possible?

Comment: It depends on when you are intending to "check".  Is it within the SELECT, UPDATE, or INSERT?

You should be able to put a UNIQUE constraint on a combination of the staff and cust id, and pre-fill those with NULL, then you won't ever be able to insert two NULL values.

However, you should really look at your code to make sure that you're never inserting a reference-record when you don't have anything referenced to.  Think of data in databases as "raw".  If the data inserted is too easily capable of providing incorrect "derived" information then you have code issues on INSERT and/or SELECT.